# How to match up until a certain character in regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a wildcard url. However, I do not need to match from the start of the url path onwards.

Example: *.performance.com is all I am trying to match not *.performance.com/home

Anything from the forward slash onwards is not needed. I cant seem to state it to stop at this point this is what I have so far

```
/(\*\.)([\w\d]+\.)+[\w\d]+$/
```

Here is a regex101 link:

https://regex101.com/r/dU42kT/1

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Remove the anchor at the end, omit the capturing groups if you don't need them and note that `\w` also matches `\d` like  `\*\.(?:\w+\.)+\w+` https://regex101.com/r/Hskq8X/1

Answer (score 1):

This part `[\w\d]+`can be written as `\w+` as it also matches digits.

The capturing groups can be omitted if you don't need the separate values. You can omit the anchor `$` at the end of the string, as a word character does not match `/`

You can use

```
\*\.(?:\w+\.)+\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hskq8X/1)